# Is there a way to map a key to another key only in VSCode

Tags: vim, keyboard, visual-studio-code

Specifically, I want to map the CAPS-LOCK key to the escape key, but only when im in Visual Studio Code.

(This serves to improve the VIM VScode experience)

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98578 the answer is there is not a way to map one key to another in vscode.

Comment: any workaround?